# SSRS 2016 native mode fail to connect SharePoint list datasource

Tags: 2016, reporting-services, sql-server-2016, report-builder, datasource

We are using SP2016 with SQL 2016 standard (13.0.5026.0 SQL Server 2016 Service Pack 2 (SP2)). SSRS feature is enabled in SQL server and service started. I am able to browse the SSRS portal with http://sqlserver/reports. Also in my SQL 2016 report builder, I can connect to report server http://sqlserver/ReportServer/

Then I setup my first datasource in a report. Connection Type is **Microsoft SharePoint List**. In connection string field I type in "https://sharepoint.com/sites/dev". This url can be browsed properly from my PC as well as within SQL server.

In **Credentials** I tried all the combination I can think of. I have tried my personal account (which is site collection admin) and sql admin and farm admin etc. All results in error message

> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: An error occurred when
>   accessing the specified SharePoint list. The connection string might
>   not be valid. Verify that the connection string is correct.  ---> 
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.DataExtensions.SharePointList.SPDPException:
>   An error occurred when accessing the specified SharePoint list. The
>   connection string might not be valid. Verify that the connection
>   string is correct.  --->  System.Net.WebException: The underlying
>   connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> 
>   System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport
>   connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote
>   host. --->  System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection
>   was forcibly closed by the remote host    at
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ReportingService2010Impl.TestConnectForDataSourceDefinition(DataSourceDefinition
>   DataSourceDefinition, String UserName, String Password, String&
>   ConnectError)    at
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.WebServer.ReportingService2010.TestConnectForDataSourceDefinition(DataSourceDefinition
>   DataSourceDefinition, String UserName, String Password, String&
>   ConnectError)

I have tried to upload the report to SSRS web portal (http://sqlserver/reports) and also fail in same error.

May I know what could be the problem? Is there any patch specific for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further test, I believe it is a bug or malfunction of SQL builder 2016.

First, in Visual Studio 2017, I tested I can create the same datasource "https://sharepoint.com/sites/dev". No connection error.

Second, in sql report builder 2016, I changed the source URL from https to http, now it is working.